# Binary decimal conversion with arrays

Tags: arrays, c, binary, decimal

Do you have a simple idea of how we go from a binary number to a decimal number in C without doing any divisions (because I can have very big numbers), maybe only with masks (&, |, << or >>) .
I have a table like this:

```
tab[20] = {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1};
```

and I would like this :

```
tab[6] = {5,9,6,2,5,3};
```

Is this something that can be done ? Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the type of 'tab'?

Comment: You can use "0b" to define your variable using a binary.

Comment: e.g.: uint32_t val = 0b10010001100100011101;

Comment: then to separate the digits, you can use modulo (%) and division. e.g.: uint32_t digit_1 = val % 10;

Comment: If you can, do not store booleans into array of bytes. it is not optimized in term of memory usage

Comment: @The_Average_Engineer the `0b` notation is not standard and is not supported by every compiler.

Comment: yes I assumed gcc

Answer (score 1):

> idea of how we go from a binary number to a decimal number (can have very big numbers)

For each binary digit, scale the decimal destination by 2 and add the digit.

**Pseudo code**

```
some_integer_type tab2[] = {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1};
some_integer_type tab10[big_enough];

zero fill tab10[]
for (each i element in tab2[] starting with index 0) {
  // scale tab10[] by 2 and add tab2[]
  carry = tab2[i]
  for (each j element in tab10[] starting with the last index) {
    sum = (tab10[j] << 1) | carry;
    if (sum >= 10) {
      sum -= 10;
      carry = 1;
    } else {
      carry = 0;
    }
    tab10[i] = sum;
  }
}
print tab10[]
```

To do `>=, -= 10` with only `&, |, << or >>`, create helper functions: [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

No division and up to 64 bit. This is "big". The bin-to-dec is done with `sprintf()`. That digit-string can then be converted to an array of integers like your `tab[6]`

```
char bittab[64] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0};
long num = 0, dupl = 1;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof bittab; i++) {
    num += dupl * bittab[i];
    dupl *= 2;
}
char decstring[30];
sprintf(decstring, "%ld\n", num);
for (i = 0; i < strlen(decstring); i++)
    printf("%d\n", decstring[i] - '0');
```

The output is:

```
3
2
7
6
7
-38
```

This can be written into a dectab[] array, excluding the null terminator byte.

(I made the bits ascending to leave the size open.)

Comment: Note: `long` may only be 32-bit and maybe use an unsigned type here.  Consider `unsigned long long`